# Getting the url of a local jasper report (.jrxml) file in java

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using netBeans and I'm trying to generate a report unsing Jasper Report
Can I get the url (of the local jrxml file) of the report 
which is stored in the the following directory structure

```
My_project
   |_build
   |_dist
   |_nbproject
   |_src
     |_my_project
     |_META_INF
     |_report.jrxml
     |_report.jasper
```

I dont want to add the absolute path to my report file
I want java /java classes to do that for me
is there any way to get the file name parameter in

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load ("__MY_REPORT_NAME");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
InputStream in = 
      getClass().getResourceAsStream("/relative/path/to/yourReport.jasper");
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(in);
```

Comment: actually I want my app to ge the relative url of the file (when I'm using netbeans and when I'm deploying it as a jar file)

Comment: @charanraj it should be in the same location in both cases - relative to the classpath. Otherwise you have an environment issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer.I'll try to figure it out :( your answer surely is a great help to me.Thanks for showing concern and answering my question

Comment: relative path to classpath root means that it does not depend on where your jar/bin folders are - you are location resources relative to the jar root, or the the bin folder

Comment: hey Mr Bozho .thanks I got my answer+ it helped in solving my problem .Thanks a lot  :)